# TeamCity pass codebase changes to next build

Tags: teamcity

I have a TeamCity build that sometimes fails too early.

What I mean by that is that the first few steps are for "provisioning" (setting up the testing environment) and the testing of my code itself comes later.
Sometimes (for whatever reason) the build fails during one of the "provisioning" steps. This is not a problem since running the build again usually works fine.

But - the "changes" are not passed along to the next run of the build.

I am using this command as part of my build to output the "changes" that came from my codebase:

```
copy "%system.teamcity.build.changedFiles.file%" changelog.txt
```

So I need a way to tell TeamCity "hey, ignore the last run, that failure doesn't count because it didn't test my code, I want the next run to contain the same 'changes' in `system.teamcity.build.changedFiles.file`"

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried build chains with dependencies? They can be set up to only execute if the build (including tests) is successful: http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2012/04/teamcity-build-dependencies-2/